# What can cause cmake (2.8.4 and 7) to fail after upgrade of Visual Studion 10 Express to Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

C:\Users\xxxx\lindenhg\3p\hacd-k-wip\buil>cmake -G"Visual Studio 10" ../Source
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10

Gets to here, hangs, and I ctrl-c out.

An nmake project will complete including the test above.

After ctrl-c out, I can cd to C:\Users\xxxx\lindenhg\3p\hacd-k-wip\buil\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp>
Then, cl testCCompiler.c and the program compiles against the cl.exe in Visual Studio 10/vc/bin with no hiccups.

Uninstalled and reinstalled cmake.

Before with express only cmake gave no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solved but not in a smart way. Removed all previous versions of Visual Studio and Visual Studio 10. Reinstalled Visual Studio 10